# InvalidOperationException Ellipse not Found after Binding "IsChecked"

Tags: wpf, xaml, styles, togglebutton

I am using a Togglebutton Style from [here](https://mharwood.uk/wpf-material-design-toggle-button/) after Binding the IsChecked Property to my ViewModel the Program crashes with a `System.InvalidOperationException` Ellipse not found in  "System.Windows.Controls.ControlTemplate".

The Style looks like this:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
   <Setter Property="Template">
      <Setter.Value>
         <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
            <Viewbox>
               <Border x:Name="Border"
                  CornerRadius="10"
                  Background="#FFE2E2E2"
                  Width="40"
                  Height="20">
                  <Border.Effect>
                      <DropShadowEffect ShadowDepth="0.5"
                         Direction="0"
                         Opacity="0.3" />
                   </Border.Effect>
                   <Ellipse x:Name="Ellipse"
                      Fill="#FF909090"
                      Stretch="Uniform"
                      Margin="-8 -4"
                      Stroke="Gray"
                      StrokeThickness="0.2"
                      HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                   <Ellipse.Effect>
                      <DropShadowEffect BlurRadius="10"
                         ShadowDepth="1"
                         Opacity="0.3"
                         Direction="260" />
                   </Ellipse.Effect>
                </Ellipse>
             </Border>
          </Viewbox>
          <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
             <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Checked">
                <BeginStoryboard>
                   <Storyboard>
                      <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="Ellipse"
                         Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Ellipse.Fill).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                         To="#00facc"
                         Duration="0:0:0.05"
                         AccelerationRatio="0.7"
                         DecelerationRatio="0.3" />
                      <ThicknessAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="Ellipse"
                         Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin"
                         To="20 -4 -8 -4"
                         Duration="0:0:0.15"
                         AccelerationRatio="0.7"
                         DecelerationRatio="0.3" />
                      </Storyboard>
                   </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Unchecked">
                  <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                      <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="Ellipse"
                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Ellipse.Fill).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                        To="#00facc"
                        Duration="0:0:0.05"
                        AccelerationRatio="0.7"
                        DecelerationRatio="0.3" />
                     <ThicknessAnimation 
                        Storyboard.TargetName="Ellipse"                                                            
                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin"
                        To="-8 -4"
                        Duration="0:0:0.15"
                        AccelerationRatio="0.7"
                        DecelerationRatio="0.3" />
                     </Storyboard>
                  </BeginStoryboard>
               </EventTrigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
         </ControlTemplate>
      </Setter.Value>
   </Setter>
</Style>
```

And my usage like this:

```
<ToggleButton Grid.Column="0"
   Grid.Row="2"
   IsChecked="{Binding IsAutostop}"/>
```

I'd like to use the style AND be able to use the "IsChecked" Property.

EDIT

Thanks for the comments.

I open the window with a Service bound to a command in a taskbaricon.

The Service:

```
    class WindowService
    {
        public void OpenOptionsView(MainViewModel mvm)
        {
            OptionsView optionsView = new OptionsView { DataContext = mvm };
            optionsView.Show();
        }
    }
```

The important parts of the MainviewModel:

```
public ICommand OpenOptionsViewCommand { get; private set; }
public bool IsAutostop { get { return Settings.Default.Autostop; } set { Settings.Default.Autostop = value; Settings.Default.Save(); OnPropertyChanged(); } }

public MainViewModel() 
{
   OpenOptionsViewCommand = new RelayCommand(OpenOptionsView, param => true);
}

private void OpenOptionsView(object o)
{
   WindowService ws = new WindowService();
   ws.OpenOptionsView(this);
}
```

I stored my TaskbarIcon in a seperated View:

```
   <tb:TaskbarIcon>
      <tb:TaskbarIcon.ContextMenu>
         <ContextMenu Background="#1e1e1e">
            <MenuItem Header="Programm öffnen"  
                      Foreground="White"
                      Command="{Binding OpenOptionsViewCommand}"/>
         </ContextMenu>
      </tb:TaskbarIcon.ContextMenu>
   </tb:TaskbarIcon>
```

EDIT II:

I just found out, that the problem occurs when the bound value is True and the window should be opened with a checked Togglebutton.

Comment: I have tested your code in a simple view and it works properly (except for a problem of color)

Comment: It sounds like it is working without the binding?

Comment: I have no problem of color. I can use it without the binding.

Comment: Given the limited code you have shown to us this doesn't make any sense. There is no reason why the binding would break the template or any template in general. It's more likely that something different causes the issue. Please create and post a minimal example that reproduces the issue. this allows us to review the code properly.